# Have installed tftpd-hpa on Ubuntu 20.04. tftp timeout is observed on my ICX client but the file is uploaded to the server with 0 bytes

Tags: networking

I have installed tftpd-hpa following the steps in the below link:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/TFTP

My `/etc/default/tftpd-hpa` looks like this:

```
TFTP_USERNAME="tftp"
TFTP_DIRECTORY="/var/lib/tftpboot"
TFTP_ADDRESS=":69"
TFTP_OPTIONS="--secure --create"
```

The process is up and running but when I try upload from tftp-client(ICX device), it fails as below:

```
copy running-config tftp 111.1.1.10 test
Parameter Validation Successful
............test                   0% |                               |     0  --:--:-- ETA
test                   0% |                               |     0  --:--:-- ETA
test                   0% |                               |     0  --:--:-- ETA
test                   0% |                               |     0   - stalled -
test                   0% |                               |     0   - stalled -
test                   0% |                               |     0   - stalled -
test                   0% |                               |     0   - stalled -
test                   0% |                               |     0   - stalled -

tftp: timeout

File Upload failed
File Upload Failed
```

Answer (score 0):

The described problem can have several causes. Do a few checks:

#### Bad TFTP data directory owner

```
sudo chmod tftp:tftp /var/lib/tftpboot
```

User and group owners must be `tftp`.

#### Directory write access is missing

Check the write permissions.

#### Firewall blocks access to the server

Check IPtables.

```
sudo iptables-save
sudo iptables-save | grep "69"
```

The first command shows whether the local firewall is active. If yes, then the second command should find the rule for open UDP port 69.

The situation is not entirely simple, because the data transfer takes place on ports other than UDP 69, which is used to deliver commands. Sometimes it may be necessary to turn off the firewall completely or use a special firewall module for TFTP.

#### The network communication checking

You can follow the progress of the entire TFTP communication using Wireshark quite well. To limit the selection of displayed data, use the display filter "udp".

#### TFTP client to test server functionality

In addition to the tftpd-hpa daemon, the tftp-hpa client can be installed and used.

Start the testing locally, directly on the same server running the TFTPD daemon.
Prepare small local text file:

```
echo "My text." > x.txt
cat x.txt
```

Try to upload file to TFTP server:

```
sudo apt-get install tftp-hfa
```

Usage:

```
tftp 111.1.1.10
verbose
status
put x.txt
quit
```

TFTP directory content check:

```
ls -l /var/lib/tftpboot
```

If everything is correct, try downloading the file (`get` instead of `put`). Then use a TFTP client on another computer to verify that the connection over the network is not blocked by the firewall.